# Regex to restrict a string for no more than 5 consecutive numeric characters and no more than 8 numeric characters in total

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

I'm trying to build a regex that restricts a string for no more than 5 consecutive numeric characters and no more than 8 numeric characters in total.

For example :

- 12345                      => True
- Yograj                     => True
- Yograj123456               => False
- 12345Yograj                => True
- 12345Yograj12345           => True
- Yograj123456Yograj         => False
- Yograj123Varsolkar456789   => False
- 123Yograj45678Varsolkar    => True
- A1B2C3D4e5f6g7h8i9j0       => False
- Yograj 890 Varsolkar 78455 => False

I was able to create this till now:
/**^((\d{0,5}[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,5})+|\d{0,5})$**/

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative lookahead with some alternation might be helpfull here:

```
^(?!.*\d{6}|(?:.*\d){9})[A-Za-z\d]+$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFqLXc/1)

- `^` - Start-line anchor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `.*\d{6}` - 0+ Chars other than newline followed by 6 digits.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `(?:.*\d){9}` - A non-capture group of 0+ chars other than newline followed by a single digit matched 9 times.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[A-Za-z\d]+` - Match 1+ alphanumeric characters.
- `$` - End-line anchor.